# Approximate a CDF

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, inference, nonparametric, numerical-integration

Suppose we have $n$ equations with an integral of the form $\int_0^{x_i} F(z)dz = c_i,\ i=1,\ldots,n$ where $F(y)=\mathbb{P}(X \le y)$ is an unknown cumulative distribution function of a non-negative discrete random variable $X$. $x$ is an input and $c_i$ are known. We can assume that $X \in [0,M]$ is a bounded random variable. We want $F$ to be non-decreasing with $F(0)=0$ and $F(M) = 1$.

Given the above setup, I have the following two questions

1. What are some effective methods to learn $F$?
2. Is it possible to get guarantees on the number of samples $n$ ?

I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the constraints are $$\int_0^{x_i} F(z)dz = c_i\qquad i=1,...,n$$there exists one step function with jumps only at $x_1,x_2,...,M$ that satisfies this collection of constraints and converges to $F$ as $n$ grows to infinity.